# OpenCV_Python: Lightness Channel Manipulation, Trying to get same brightness to all images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, brightness

I am hoping to fix my uneven brightness/lightness of all my images(Hoping to get all brightness).
After getting the difference in lightness channel for my loop images to my reference images. I add the difference and save it to new images...however after checking the new images, I realised I still gotten uneven brightness...Is there anything wrong with my coding??? Any help or correction is appreciated. I have tried this code on both LAB and HSV colorspace, still the same. Below is the code and a couple of result that I got.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2


path = 'R:\\Temp\\zzzz\\AlignedPhoto_in_PNG\\'
path1 = 'R:\\Temp\\zzzz\\Testing1\\'


img = cv2.imread(path + 'aligned_IMG_1770.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a = np.mean(img[:,:,0])

for i in range (1770,1869):
    img1 = cv2.imread(path + 'aligned_IMG_%d.png'%(i))
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    img1[:,:,0], img1[:,:,1], img1[:,:,2] = cv2.split(img1)
    print(img1[:,:,0])
    b = np.mean(img1[:,:,0])
    diff= b-a
    print(diff)
    img1[:,:,0] = img1[:,:,0] + diff
    img1 = cv2.merge([img1[:,:,0], img1[:,:,1], img1[:,:,2]])
    print(img1[:,:,0])
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite(path1 + 'Testing1_%d.png'%(i), img1)
```

Also, any guidance on how I can edit the existing code to make sure after adding the difference, the new value does not exceed the max/min range of Lightness Channel in LAB or the max/min range of Value Channel in HSV? I realised after addition if the new value is >255 , the value jump to starting counting from 1. I googled around on how to fix this or set the range but I dun understand how to do it

Below is a few images result I got from above code. Hopefully that help to identify what went wrong with my code as I am still getting uneven brightness for the new images after adding the difference.

```
[[ 39  39  39 ...,  38  38  36]
 [ 39  38  39 ...,  39  39  39]
 [ 40  40  40 ...,  39  39  39]
 ..., 
 [119 119 122 ..., 165 166 167]
 [118 118 120 ..., 169 166 166]
 [115 116 117 ..., 175 169 167]]
0.0
[[ 39  39  39 ...,  38  38  36]
 [ 39  38  39 ...,  39  39  39]
 [ 40  40  40 ...,  39  39  39]
 ..., 
 [119 119 122 ..., 165 166 167]
 [118 118 120 ..., 169 166 166]
 [115 116 117 ..., 175 169 167]]
[[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [117 119 119 ..., 165 163 131]
 [117 117 118 ..., 170 166 131]
 [115 116 116 ..., 176 171 134]]
-1.48181156101
[[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [115 117 117 ..., 163 161 129]
 [115 115 116 ..., 168 164 129]
 [113 114 114 ..., 174 169 132]]
[[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [  0  97 115 ..., 165 164 165]
 [  0  96 114 ..., 169 166 164]
 [  0  95 113 ..., 175 170 166]]
-3.69765536832
[[253 253 253 ..., 253 253 253]
 [253 253 253 ..., 253 253 253]
 [253 253 253 ..., 253 253 253]
 ..., 
 [253  93 111 ..., 161 160 161]
 [253  92 110 ..., 165 162 160]
 [253  91 109 ..., 171 166 162]]
```

Comment: don't think too complicated. if you calculate an offset and you get wrong results. the first thing to do is  check your offset calculation by using a example. or just think what would happen if a is brighter than b.... don't make other people think for you

Comment: @Piglet the diff will be diff = a - b even if I am taking my first images brightness which is a as my reference brightness value?

Comment: @Piglet i still do not understand how to set the cap for pixel to within the channel range....really any example is really helpful for me in understanding and learning. I learned the most through example/practical as sometimes i dont understand when i read through the documentation or theory

Comment: well you just cap with max(old value + diff, 255). and min(0, oldvalue + diff). but this will give you negative values and values above 255 so you have to use another data type and scale your image back to byte values later. otherwise you will end up with a wrong average brightness. maybe you should just do this for set of values, not with an image. it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Piglet i still getting back uneven brightness result. I do notice there were different from the original photo and edited photo..however it seem like i am doing using global correction value instead of adaptive correction(which i hv no idea how) need some help on how to start with this?

Comment: how do you define uneven brightness? if you do this properly the average brightness of all images should be identical. if you want to achieve something else you of course have to do something else.

Comment: @Piglet i had use cv2 add function when adding the difference that i got. I read that add function in cv2 automatically clip the value within (0,255). The following images is what I am trying to explain what my uneven brightness problem was. http://imgur.com/a/Hwe5n  Save the images and tab through you will realised the brightness issue is very obvious.

Comment: I told you that clamping your values to 0-255 will cause wrong results and still you come back and tell me that you did clamp them after all and complain that you get wrong results.... VALUE.  imagine you have two 5 liter buckets. one hase 4 liters of water in it, the other one 1 liter. this gives you an average of 2.5 liters per bucket. now you have another set of buckets with an average of 4 liters.  to get the same average you have to add 1.5 liters to each bucket. but doing so you will spill 0.5 liters of water on bucket 1. so your new average is only 3.75 liters...  now think.

Comment: @piglet Still got back with different brightness...after flipping through my images, do you think i am using the right approach? i feel like using the mean brightness average might not be the correct approach. I am only getting global value on the brightness different. Any other method you can suggest to me? So far, I tried equalization the luminance channel using LAB/HSV/YCB_CR, couldnt fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why maths is a skill every programmer should have.

You correct your brightness by adding diff.

So if you want a to equal the sum of b and diff

```
a = b + diff
```

and you know a and be. then how do you get diff?

```
diff = a - b
```

not

```
diff = b - a
```

Otherwise you will make darker images darker and brighter images brighter instead of bringing them to your reference mean a...

Of course using a global offset will cause problems with pixels that exceed your value range. You have to work around this problem. Otherwise your new mean will be wrong.

Comment: the diff will be diff = a - b even if I am taking my first images brightness which is a as my reference brightness value?

Comment: @SacreD I don't understand what you mean. in your code image a is your reference. image b changes for every image in your loop. if image b is brighter than a you have to reduce it's brightness to get the same brightness as in b, hence your offset must be negative. if you do it your way your offset is positive and you get an even brighter image...